# How do I write a json array from R that has a sequence of lat and long?

Tags: json, r

How do I write a json array from R that has a sequence of lat and long?

I would like to write:

```
[[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]]
```

the best I can do is:

```
toJSON(matrix(1:6, ncol = 2, byrow = T))
#"[ [ 1, 2 ],\n[ 3, 4 ],\n[ 5, 6 ] ]"
```

How can I wrap the thing in another array (the json kind)?
This is important to me so I can write files into a geojson format as a LineString.

Comment: Can you show the final format with `LineString`?

Comment: In case you weren't aware, the `rgdal` package can write out geojson. For example: `library(rgdal); library(sp); xy <- data.frame(id=seq_len(100), x=runif(100, 145, 150), y=runif(100, -38, -35)); coordinates(xy) <- ~x+y; writeOGR(xy, 'xy.js', layer='', driver="GeoJSON")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use `fromJSON` to get the target object :

```
ll <- fromJSON('[[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]]')

str(ll)
List of 1
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : num [1:2] 1 2
  ..$ : num [1:2] 3 4
  ..$ : num [1:2] 5 6
```

So we should create , a list of unnamed list, each containing  2 elements:

```
 xx <- list(setNames(split(1:6,rep(1:3,each=2)),NULL))
identical(toJSON(xx),'[[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]]')
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Very clever! I'll remember this.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm ashamed I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `matrix`

```
 m1 <- matrix(1:6, ncol=2, byrow=T)
```

may be this helps:

```
 library(rjson)
 paste0("[",toJSON(setNames(split(m1, row(m1)),NULL)),"]")
 #[1] "[[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]]"
```